# Spherical harmonics

Tags: lighting, cubemap, spherical-harmonics

I'm currently trying to implement a GI system for diffuse lighting and wanted to do so in spherical harmonics.

Now i have read what else i could find and i know the general idea of how to get from cubemap to SH coefficients but there is just one thing that is bugging me a lot.

In Peter-Pike Sloan's "Stupid Spherical Harmonics (SH) Tricks" [1] on page 9 of the pdf he gives this pseudo-code for the process:

```
    float f[],s[];
    float fWtSum=0;
    Foreach(cube map face)
        Foreach(texel)
             float fTmp = 1 + u^2+v^2;
             float fWt = 4/(sqrt(fTmp)*fTmp);
             EvalSHBasis(texel,s);
             f += t(texel)*fWt*s; // vector
             fWtSum += fWt;
    f *= 4*Pi/fWtSum; // area of sphere
```

The theory, "evaluate sh basis in direction of each texel center and weight by solid angle", okay thus far,
Now comes the stupid part;
what the hell is he doing? What is he taking the euclidean distance for and and what is going on with `4/(sqrt(ftmp)*ftmp)` i see no trigeometry so i am not assuming he is calculating the solid angle here? I have also looked at other implementations to derive solid angle from cubemap texels and they are.. different

He further states that `EvalSHBasis` needs to "normalize the input coordinate (on a cube face) and simply evaluate the sh basis functions in that direction".  Now what is he normalizing here? i am lost.

[1]P.-P. Sloan, “Stupid Spherical Harmonics (SH) Tricks”  https://www.ppsloan.org/publications/StupidSH36.pdf

Comment: Noone?.. still can't figure this out..